# How to type a function that transforms a tuple in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to write a function like this in Typescript?

```
type Boxed<T> = { value: T };

function unbox<T>(box: Boxed<T>): T {
    return box.value;
}

function unboxTuple<T extends Boxed<unknown>[]>(
    ...tuple: T
) {
    return tuple.map(unbox);
}

const boxedTuple: [Boxed<number>, Boxed<string>] = [
    {value: 4}, {value: "foo"}
];
```

I feel like this should be possible, but this code doesn't work: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gDwgEwDwBUB8UC8UDeUAbgIYA2ArhAFxTpQC+A3AFAsBmFAdgMbACWcLlG4AjRBkwAKcQlrwkaLAEpa9fCyhaoAJwjAKO4bIB0pShFYM2nXgKEius9BTBkIGKBATAIXZADOsIgoqNwA1lxwAO5cmADaALrSmtom6QZuNHQsygSpWnoGRlCZ7iYAtiRgUmKIylZsPEIBwFCyKC5ZtPEKoVwUFaIQOpgANMGKqK06-FwA5piJuFDxBQTmVLQALAwT+JvZAETscHBH1omsLM1cAXDlZHDztU6IXe4yIcgfEMoNQA)

Answer (score 1):

To get the appropriate types you need to use a mapped type over the tuple to extract each type from the box:

```
type UnboxAll<T extends Record<number, Boxed<any>>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Boxed<infer V> ? V : never
};
function unboxTuple<T extends Boxed<unknown>[]>(
    ...tuple: T
) {
    return tuple.map(unbox) as UnboxAll<T>
}

const boxedTuple: [Boxed<number>, Boxed<string>] = [
    { value: 4 }, { value: "foo" }
];

let z = unboxTuple(...boxedTuple); // [number, string]
)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gDwgEwDwBUB8UC8UDeUAbgIYA2ArhAFxTpQC+A3AFAsBmFAdgMbACWcLlG4AjRBkwAKcQlrwkaLAEpa9fCyhaoAJwjAKO4bIB0pShFYMWoSFACqXWQEEyZDFAgJgELsgDOUABKEDxwOmhcFAC2ohA6ADSwiCioJFwgmFm4BJraANoAClD8wgDWECBw7HQAumpFtZ7evgHJiqil7PFQAGrYAPx9ULRcEETxLMwc3HyCwmKI6BRgZBAeXj5+gQqp3GVccADuXJj5tdJ5WiY3Bqs0dCzKudq6+obCd2sm0SRgUosEM8SIFHC43JIpmwwlx-MAoLIUMt7rR8rtIjE4jpMEl0ag4TpSgBzTBNPD5K4EYjkKi0AAsjCShHMtKgACJ2HA4GzGCxaqwWGt4QAvHKA5FrKQ3EyI5ASiDKJhQAD0yqg+SisXiSQJxNqTyAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can either change this:

```js
function unboxTuple<T extends Boxed<unknown>[]>(
    tuple: T
) {
    return tuple.map(unbox);
}
```

Or this:

```
console.log(unboxTuple(...boxedTuple));
```